# Check user's rights on a SSRS

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to check if user's roles on a SSRS contains rights to certain tasks?

Now I can only *try to perform* an operation and show an error if an user cannot perform the operation, but I want to inform an user about possible problems before he starts to do his job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you a list of permissions; you can filed down by username to see a single users or groups permissions.

```
select 
    dbo.Users.UserName,
    dbo.Roles.RoleName,
    substring(dbo.catalog.path,2,LEN(dbo.catalog.path)) FolderName
from 
    dbo.PolicyUserRole 
left join dbo.Users 
     on dbo.Users.UserID=dbo.PolicyUserRole.UserID
left join dbo.Roles 
     on dbo.Roles.RoleID=dbo.PolicyUserRole.RoleID
inner join dbo.Catalog 
     on dbo.Catalog.PolicyID=dbo.PolicyUserRole.PolicyID
where 
    TYPE=1
```